# Firebase / MomentJS Inconsistent Values

Tags: javascript, firebase, momentjs

I have this:

```
  init(userId: string = this.authProvider.currentUserId) {
    this._subscription.add(this.db.list(`meetings/${userId}`)
      .subscribe((meetings: any[]) => {
        this._meetings = meetings.map((meeting) => {
          meeting.Date = meeting.Date;
          meeting.Ends = moment.tz(meeting.Ends, 'HH:mm', meeting.Location.TimeZone).local().format('HH:mm');
          meeting.Starts = moment.tz(meeting.Starts, 'HH:mm', meeting.Location.TimeZone).local().format('HH:mm');
          return Meeting.Parse(meeting);
        });
      }));
  }
```

On any change from firebase, `meeting.Starts`, `meeting.Ends` values are preserved after being parsed by moment.tz.

So assuming on first subscription `meeting.Starts` is `11:00`. After doing `meeting.Starts = moment.tz...` which will result in say `13:00` then next time anything happens on firebase end and the subscription is triggered, the value of `Starts` becomes `15:00` assuming the timezone adds 2 hours.

(The value in firebase is correct...) What's happening?

Comment: An explanation for the downvote would be helpful FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using AngularFire2.

The problem is that you are mutating the items in the list. When changes occur, AngularFire2 updates only the items that are affected by the change. However, you are mutating all of the items - so `moment.tz` will be re-applied to any items that have not changed.

One solution would be to not mutate the items:

```
init(userId: string = this.authProvider.currentUserId) {
  this._subscription.add(this.db.list(`meetings/${userId}`)
    .subscribe((meetings: any[]) => {
      this._meetings = meetings.map(meeting => Meeting.Parse({
        ...meeting,
        Ends: moment.tz(meeting.Ends, 'HH:mm', meeting.Location.TimeZone).local().format('HH:mm'),
        Starts: moment.tz(meeting.Starts, 'HH:mm', meeting.Location.TimeZone).local().format('HH:mm');
      }));
    });
}
```

Or, without the spread properties syntax:

```
init(userId: string = this.authProvider.currentUserId) {
  this._subscription.add(this.db.list(`meetings/${userId}`)
    .subscribe((meetings: any[]) => {
      this._meetings = meetings.map(meeting => Meeting.Parse(
        Object.assign({}, meeting, {
          Ends: moment.tz(meeting.Ends, 'HH:mm', meeting.Location.TimeZone).local().format('HH:mm'),
          Starts: moment.tz(meeting.Starts, 'HH:mm', meeting.Location.TimeZone).local().format('HH:mm');
        })
      ));
    });
}
```